# Extracting Tuple from Bag in PIG

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-pig

FILE COntent (test.txt):

```
Some    specific    column      value: x192.168.1.2     blah       blah
Some    specific    row        value: y192.168.1.3      blah       blah
Some    specific    field      value: z192.168.1.4     blah      blah
```

PIG QUERY:

```
A = LOAD 'test.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (data1: chararray , data2: chararray , data3: chararray, data4: chararray , data5: chararray , data6: chararray);

B = foreach A generate data3, data4;

C = filter B by data3 matches 'row';

D = foreach C generate data4;

E = foreach D generate TOKENIZE(data4);
```

Output :

```
((value:), (y192.168.1.3))
```

Now i want to extract specific tuple in this output bag, say second tuple (y192.168.1.3).
After this i want to extract the IP address. I am trying to do with UDFs but got stuck.

Comment: Pig allows regex matching.  Have you tried that?

Comment: is regex in pig is same as java???

Comment: I tried with this : E = foreach D generate REGEX_EXTRACT(message,'Internet:*') As result; but it throws an error :- ERROR 1045: Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.REGEX_EXTRACT as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast. 

My Ip in message is written as Internet:192.x.x.x

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Flatten Operator](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/basic.html#flatten) to flatten the bag and then use filter to extract the ip address.

```
E = foreach C generate flatten(TOKENIZE(data4));
F = filter E by $0 matches '.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+'
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Tried this but it returns no result.

I also tried with this :
 E = foreach D generate REGEX_EXTRACT(message,'Internet:*') As result;

but it throws an error  :- ERROR 1045: Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.REGEX_EXTRACT as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.



My Ip in message is written as Internet:192.x.x.x

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake. The first line should be **E = foreach C generate flatten(TOKENIZE(data4));**

Comment: I think you should specify the index. So it should be **E = foreach D generate REGEX_EXTRACT($0,'(.*):(.*)', 2);** . Here is the sample [code](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/func.html#regex-extract). But there is an error in the sample, '\' should be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I would do.

PIG Script

```
A = LOAD 'test.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (data1: chararray , data2: chararray , data3: chararray, data4: chararray , data5: chararray , data6: chararray);
B = foreach A generate data3, data4;
C = filter B by data3 matches 'row';
D = foreach C generate data4;
E = foreach D generate REGEX_EXTRACT($0,'value: .([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+).*', 1);
```

Output

```
(192.168.1.3)
```

If needed, you can use a more crazy regexp to extract the IP address: [Extract ip addresses from Strings using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875013/extract-ip-addresses-from-strings-using-regex)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class someClass extends EvalFunc<String>
{
   public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
     DataBag bag = (DataBag)input.get(0);
     Iterator<Tuple> it = bag.iterator();
     Tuple tup;
     for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
     {
       tup = it.next();
     }
     String ipString = tup.get(0);
     String ip = //get ip from string with a regex
     return ip;
   }
 }
```

of course you should add some input checks (null inputs, bag sized 1, etc) and secure the code.

Comment: thanks for d reply..but its not giving desired result.
tup.get(0) returns complete message ((value:), (y192.168.1.3))
  not (y192.168.1.3)