# Regex in Streamsets

Tags: java, regex, streamsets

Hi I want to break a log file using Streamsets. the log is like,

```
Deny tcp src dmz:77.77.77.7/61112 dst dmz:55.55.56.57/139 by access-group "outside_access_in" [0x8b3ecfdc, 0x0]
```

There may be more than 2 IP's also in the log and I'm trying to capture the only 1st and 2nd IP address from my log. It's written that Streamsets use Java REGEX patterns.

what I did till now in Expression Evaluator processor in Streamsets is,

```
${str:regExCapture(record:value('/Message'),'(\\d+[.]\\d+[.]\\d+[.]\\d+/?\\d*)', 1)}
```

Any idea how to capture the 2nd IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
${str:regExCapture(record:value('/Message'),'^(?:.*?(\\d+(?:[.]\\d+){3}(?:/\\d+)?)){2}', 1)}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zuAyLy/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:.*?(\\d+(?:[.]\\d+){3}(?:/\\d+)?)){2}` - two consecutive occurrences of

  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
  - `(\\d+(?:[.]\\d+){3}(?:/\\d+)?)` - Capturing group 1 (its value will be returned by `str:regExCapture` since the last argument is set to `1`):

    - `\\d+` -  1+ digits
    - `(?:[.]\\d+){3}` - three occurrences of `.` and 1+ digits
    - `(?:/\\d+)?` - an optional sequence of `/` and 1+ digits.

Since the contents in a group is re-written when several occurrences are captured within one match operation, Group 1 will only contain the second IP value.

Note that a better (safer, more precise) IP pattern would be `(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[0-1]?\\d?\\d)(?:\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[0-1]?\\d?\\d)){3}`, see [Extract ip addresses from Strings using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875013/extract-ip-addresses-from-strings-using-regex). So, you may also write the command as

```
 ${str:regExCapture(record:value('/Message'),'^(?:.*?\\b((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[0-1]?\\d?\\d)(?:\\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[0-1]?\\d?\\d)){3}(?:/\\d+)?)){2}', 1)}
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zuAyLy/3).