# Only match IP addresses and not other numbers

Tags: python, regex, ip-address, python-re, named-captures

I​ want the following regex code to return an output of IP addresses without returning other number values as IP from the source file.

**The Code:**

```
import re

logdata = 146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622
for item in re.finditer("(?P<host>[\d.]+)", logdata):
    print(item.groupdict())
```

**Required output:**

```
{'host': '146.204.224.152'}
```

**U​nwanted output:**

```
{'host': '6811'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
(?P<host>(\d+\.){3}\d+)
```

Comment: 146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622

How can I return the date and time please!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```py
import re
logdata = r'146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622'
for item in re.finditer(r"\b(?P<host>(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3})\b", logdata):
    print(item.groupdict())
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##jY/BTsMwEETv@YpVLrUl4tgbO9AIyBVxIRK5JTm0jdNaonbkukhA@fZgKj6APbyZlUba2fkjHJwtlsUcZ@cDeJ28uf24CRt4AL8SsmTIJUOUTCiEDCatT6G8EwI6FPnz2ebIxboSqpKqQgkZv@V8gLR5eW0hN3anbTDv5lPDU9s2uWAihYIjyBJxlUzOgwn6CMbG02wydoyrJz7tt6Ru7g/uFB5JXaHqeKaGC0aRQ8R6uHRcDPXVXlHTmOvZf8P0q/im/Ta9gb9/aZVAnNkbG8hvJ7b37jyPZhcIpcvyAw).

**Results**: `{'host': '146.204.224.152'}`.

See [Extract ip addresses from Strings using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875013/extract-ip-addresses-from-strings-using-regex).

Getting both `host` and `time` from a log line like you have:

```py
import re
logdata = r'146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622'
match_data = re.search(r'^(?P<host>\S+).*?\[(?P<time>.*?)]', logdata)
if match_data:
    print(match_data.groupdict())
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##RY5Nb8IwEETv@RUrLonb4ngXJ9CIj2vVSyORG9AqCoZYauzIWSq1fz6lUhFzm3d4M/03t97NxtF2vQ8MwUSf/nysuYYVhBh1LklpSaQlZgRTOBkzcL5AhB1h@npxKSl8LjArdFaQhqmaK3WASfm2rSC1rjGO7Zf9MfBSVWWKEicwUwQ6J4qjruam/bjNGTmYOjRtEuL3ZFMuWz/wer99FPJhs9/9EbadWV@bOMRP8H9URPYEd1ERwTV9sI6TO5Xn4C/90TacCDGOvw).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?P<host>                  group and capture to (?P=host):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of (?P=host)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?P<time>                  group and capture to (?P=time):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of (?P=time)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ]                        ']'
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! That's a long nerdy piece of regex! lol!
Please, could this piece of regex return the date and time from the same source file as I shared before?

("(?P<time>[\[][\d][\w][\/][\:][\s][\-][\d]+)(?=[\]])", logdata)

i want an output like:

"time":"21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700",